# How to add text mark to a Vega Lite grouped bar chart

Tags: data-visualization, vega-lite

I wasn't able to add a text mark layer to a grouped bar chart, I've tried editing the [Vega Lite example](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/bar_grouped.html) to add sum label on top of every bar:

[image]
https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/bar_grouped

But what happens is either "layer" property wasn't accepted, or bars get squashed into one bar. How to make this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want to add a text mark to a faceted chart, the pattern to use is a [Layered view](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/layer.html) within a [Facet Operator](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/facet.html#facet-operator).

For example ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA29zQgegA4HtdFVoBLfAOwDoArAZ0pAF8AaEKZCCugM32QC28ANqgepVFACmyDJCiIBVAJ5SIyAAQBeLRoBMABiPMWoAMYRUZ4tClzoiqnSkAPbbr0aA-BoDkAMSkBSylfDTg-AFkQ3xA2CDoMAHMpCjAZZgBdNgB3UjAoAAt4UDppXHgARj1WEB4IMykoErrSKVQwDAgUuPZlXDs4EH4wUgpLExA6AbMW1LN8UYokluUW7qTkKSTbDDpFXvF2zqGBwlQ7Nih+wZAAR0QuKFIYZ4A3S5AIF1JEhHYXhcMAQiCRnow2Jt8vB6qhnExai4WkcOslUulZFcbhgKPgBGMJvEfn9QM8oEChswEWwSKpZHBRCBgsgANYYABG6l680WYxW-wWqH4yLaqKGKTSGSxAxxeIJ6DYdAsFNAnGWg2EIAAxAA2ADsAFZKgBOADMvS1FgAHFadZUQJkEdTQMy2f9rjKhtIXM02GAkXAALQG+LLCnGgxsTnOVBjW74sBgIHxWNJCgYZCkJKFZq1HlLfmk1zNf4bLY7aR7A5sFEnEBnXDJvqe+6PChksgfQ78YIlkBUU2JJ2OtgLCjiQsgN5tHItMrIfAs24cLjTdSpXM1hpNOe4Bp8qoGWrfX4tMB4iBjADq+SKVSdQA)):

```
{
  "data": {"url": "data/population.json"},
  "transform": [
    {"filter": "datum.year == 2000"},
    {"calculate": "datum.sex == 2 ? 'Female' : 'Male'", "as": "gender"}
  ],
  "width": {"step": 12},
  "facet": {"field": "age", "type": "ordinal"},
  "spec": {
    "encoding": {
      "y": {
        "aggregate": "sum",
        "field": "people",
        "type": "quantitative",
        "axis": {"title": "population", "grid": false}
      },
      "x": {"field": "gender", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"title": ""}}
    },
    "layer": [
      {
        "mark": "bar",
        "encoding": {
          "color": {
            "field": "gender",
            "type": "nominal",
            "scale": {"range": ["#675193", "#ca8861"]}
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": {
          "type": "text",
          "dx": -5,
          "angle": 90,
          "baseline": "middle",
          "align": "right"
        },
        "encoding": {
          "text": {
            "aggregate": "sum",
            "field": "people",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "format": ".3s"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "view": {"stroke": "transparent"},
    "facet": {"spacing": 10},
    "axis": {"domainWidth": 1}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The solution worked and gave the expected result. The use of spec with layered view inside was something I haven't done before, and thanks for the explanation!.